Yichud of an Uncle with his nieces and nephews
If someone has 3 children, for example a 10 year old boy, 8 year old girl, & 4 year old boy. Is it ok to leave them over night with their adult uncle.
Thank you,

Not an answer because the question is closed but the UK Federation of Synagogues published a "Q&A" on Yichud which it described as "The basic elements of these halochos need to be presented in as clear a way as possible so that members of the public are armed with the information needed to ensure that daily routines remain within the realm of halachic permissibility" It is available at https://www.federation.org.uk/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/Oneg-Vayigash.2-3.pdf

Welcome to Mi Yodeya, @Surie Rosenberg.

Since MY is different from other sites you might be used to, see here https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3886/a-beginner-s-guide-to-my-how-is-this-site-different-from-other-judaism-sites/3887#3887 for a guide which might help understand the site. Great to have you learn with us!
